# How is a conditional summation possible in Cplex? like sumifs in Excel?

Tags: sum, constraints, conditional-statements, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I want to sum all used resources among times in my model (it's rcpsp model)
how can I do it in CPLEX?
at first I wrote this:

```
forall(k in K)
  forall(t in 1..f[nAct])
    sum(i in I:f[i]-d[i]<=t-1 && t<=f[i]) r[i,k] <= aR[k];
```

(note: K is a range for resources, nAct is number of activities, f[i] is an array dvar and indicates finishing time of activity i, d[i] is duration of i,r[i,k] is required resource of k for activity i and aR[k] is available resources of k.)

The problem is that the cplex doesn't accept decision variable in sum's condition.
I changed it to:

```
forall(k in K)
  forall(t in 1..f[nAct])
    sum(i in I) (f[i]-d[i]<=t-1 && t<=f[i])*r[i,k] <= aR[k];
```

But it didn't work. it made True constraints in Problem Browser after run(I don't know why) and it made this constraint ineffective.

Any Idea how  to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to put your problem into an integer programming framework.  There are [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387299599) written on this subject.  I think this is the simplest formulation.

I assume that in your problem, r[i,k] and d[i] are known and that the time horizon is broken into discrete time periods.

- on[i,t] indicator that activity i is active at time t
- start[i,t] indicator that activity i starts at the start of period t
- end[i,t] indicator that activity i finishes at the end of period t

So in[i,t] replaces the condition f[i]-d[i]<=t-1 && t<=f[i])*r[i,k]
Your constraint becomes

```
forall(k in K)
   forall(t in 1..f[nAct])
      sum(i in I : r[i,k] = 1) on[i,t] <= aR[k];
```

You also need to add constraints to enforce the definition of on, start and off.

```
   forall(t in 2..f[nAct])
      forall(i in I)
         on[i,t-1] - on[i,t] = end[i,t-1] - start[i,t];

   forall(i in I)
      on[i,0] = start[i,0];

   forall(i in I)
      sum(t in 1..f[nAct]) start[i,t] = 1;
   forall(i in I)
      sum(t in 1..f[nAct]) end[i,t] = 1;
   forall(i in I)
      sum(t in 1..f[nAct]) on[i,t] = d[i];
```

Comment: Thank you David. I found another problem in my code. Cplex doesn't accept dvar in sum's range. Do you know how to code summations that the counter is from a dvar to another dvar? i,e in this [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/d/f/2/df26e1cf51b67fbedd01ce9c68cbbef5.png) m,n are decision variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dexpr](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.3.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/Optimization_Studio/_pubskel/ps_opl_Language952.html) for manipulating decision variables. Here is an example from the same resource [IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.3.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/Optimization_Studio/_pubskel/ps_opl_Language952.html).

Without dexpr

```
dvar int x in 0..20;
dvar int y in 0..20;
dvar int d;
dvar int s;
maximize (d);
subject to {
  d==x-y;
  s==x+y;
  s<=15;
  s<=x-2*y;
  d>=2;
  d<=y+8;
  1<=d;
}
```

With dexpr

```
dvar int x in 0..20;
dvar int y in 0..20;
dexpr int d=x-y;
dexpr int s=x+y;
maximize (d);
subject to {
  s<=15;
  s<=x-2*y;
  d>=2;
  d<=y+8;
  1<=d;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: Did you check the link I provided above ?

Comment: I know the dexpr.  Cplex doesn't accept dvar in sum's range. Do you know how to code summations that the counter is from a dvar to another dvar? i,e in this link [link](http://http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/d/f/2/df26e1cf51b67fbedd01ce9c68cbbef5.png) : m,n are decision variables.

Comment: It is not possible in Cplex. You need to re-formulate your model using additional variables and constraints as David suggested. You may also  consider to change your model to a constraint programming model where variable indexing and many conditional expressions in constraints are possible. Please refer to CP Optimizer [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.1/ilog.odms.cpo.help/CP_Optimizer/topics/cpoptimizer_splash.html).