# Gurobi objective with python dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I am using Gurobi 6.0 with Python 2.7. I am curious to know if Gurobi allows the objective function to have values coming from a dictionary with indices of the decision variables. Attaching the code:

```
from gurobipy import *

d = {
     (0, 0): 0,
     (0, 1): -5,
     (1, 0): 4,
     (1, 1): 2,
     (2, 0): 0,
     (0, 2): 10
     }

m = Model()
x = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER)
y = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER)

m.update()
m.addConstr(x + y <= 2)
m.setObjective(d[(x, y)], GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.optimize()
print m.objVal
print x.x
print y.x
```

The answer to the model was

> -5.0
>
> -0.0
>
> -0.0

which clearly makes no sense because max(d[(x,y)]) = 10 happens at x=0 and y=2 as per the given data. What is the issue here? Does Gurobi even allow such dictionary references ? Is it even allowed?

Comment: You aren't passing the dictionary, you're passing one value from it (`0`, in the likely event that `x` and `y` default to zero); `d[(x, y)]` is evaluated *before* the function is called, and the *result* is the argument.

Comment: Although default x and y = 0 makes sense, should not m.objVal also return 0 and not -5 in that case? I am not sure how it came to the -5 value ..

Answer (score 4):

For a somewhat complex causal chain `d[(x,y)]` in your code is equivalent to `d[(0,1)]`, so the constant -5 winds up being your objective function.  The reasons are

- gurobi.Var has __hash__ defined
- gurobi.Var has __cmp__ defined.  It always returns a truthy object
- In your case, x and y have hash values of 0 and 1
- The python dictionary [lookup algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605279/how-do-python-dictionary-hash-lookups-work) resolves d[(x,y)] to d[(0,1)]

What you are trying to do doesn't fit into the integer programming framework.  The best way to put this into gurobi is to add [indicator variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252934/how-is-a-conditional-summation-possible-in-cplex-like-sumifs-in-excel) that x and y take on specific values.